# How can I find a Minecraft base through a picture of the base?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing a lot of Minecraft and I would simply like to know how I can find someone's base when they post a picture showing said base. It must work with Spigot.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find somebody's else coordinates through images without any plugin/mod and them knowing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372988/can-i-find-somebodys-else-coordinates-through-images-without-any-plugin-mod-and)

Answer (score 5):

The only way that it would be possible for you to find a base in Minecraft with only a picture is if the picture includes the "debug menu" open in it. The debug menu will look like the following picture (the coordinates for the player's current location are circled in red):

[image]

The debug menu can be opened buy pressing the `F3` button on your keyboard. However, if the debug menu is not included in the screenshot **it will not be possible to find the base by any known means.**

If this menu is in the screenshot, all you have to do is open the debug menu, and move your character to the coordinates shown in the screenshot, then you will have found the base.

Comment: there is absolutly a way because people have found many bases in quick succecion with only pictures

Comment: Its likely that these people either recognized landmarks in your pictures, were a server mod, or had access to the server data. It is very much not possible to find a base with only an image and no other information.

Comment: @MarineRec look for Block Rotation exploit. seems the block texture is not random, and is tied to the coordinate values (meaning - same pattern for every coordinate of every world). there are colisions, because there are not infinite patterns on a block. so block with texture type X may be the same for 1000 coordinates (no idea, random number). a few more of those and you have the exact coordinate. you don't even need the seed. if there is natural terrain nearby, if the seed is known, your location can also be found (just find the block sequence in the seed). there may be other methods (?)