# Can I find somebody's else coordinates through images without any plugin/mod and them knowing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Basically, long story short, I'm playing on a server where griefing is allowed, and somebody griefed me and started making fun of me. I want revenge.
The griefer posted a lot of images of his base in the discord server where everyone is, and I was wondering if there's a video/ forum on how to find somebody's else coordinates with images (Like Dream or SalC1 did)

I do have the world seed which should make this easier, and there's no bedrock images I can find so that method is out of the way.

Comment: You already know the name SalC1 - his [discord](https://discord.salc1.com/), it's the hub of the community dedicated to reverse-engineering seeds, coordinates etc.

Comment: The answer is a bit old - people have managed to find the "pack.png" seed.

Answer (score 2):

You can find people's bases by comparing the natural terrain in an image with the seed of the world using a program.

It would be more difficult with this specific image because it looks like they've modified natural terrain a lot with terraforming. You need to be sure that the blocks you're incorporating into your calculations are most definitely natural and not modified by players.

https://github.com/coolmann24/TerrainFinderCpp

Here's the program that you'll need. Be advised, this could be considered cheating and you could get banned if you use this program. Check with your server admins first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The way to do this is to know the seed of the world(which you have) and compare the seed's terrain to the terrain in the images. If you are playing on an older server(like 2b2t), you should probably try looking for matches of the terrain in older versions of Minecraft with different world generation before trying it in the current version. This would be able to give you the coordinates to the base. If you are a Java programmer, you can also write a program to help automate this process. In fact, this is how some base hunters on 2b2t track down bases in images, and also why many 2b2t players advice you to never take a screenshot of your base, as they can use the method I stated above to find your base and grief it/leak its coordinates. I hope this helped. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to do without a mod or plugin.

However If you are in bedrock you can use a map to see another players location (not there coordinates specifically) and you clone the players map on java

However you will need mods for the best results.

You can also use achievements or signs that a person is in the area such as a nether portal, unnatural holes in the ground ect.

Comment: It is, in fact, possible, you do not need any mods. All you need is the world seed to find coordinates of bases/places in images. Do take a look at my answer. Thank you. :)